# urllib2 http request with authentication via proxy

Tags: python

I understand the most popular way to get resources from http with authentication is using the code below.

```
import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n',   '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

My question is if I need to set up a proxy, what code should I add to the above code block? I tried the one below but it didn't work. The error message is urllib2.URLError:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
import base64


proxy_id = "ididid"
proxy_pw = "password"
proxyhandler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://"+proxy_id+":"+proxy_pw+"@proxy:8080"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxyhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)


request = urllib2.Request("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n',   '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your proxy server require you to use user/pass authentication you should use the [`ProxyBasicAuthHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#proxybasicauthhandler-objects):

```
import urllib2
import base64


proxy_id = "ididid"
proxy_pw = "password"

proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://proxy:8080'})
proxy_auth_handler = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler()
proxy_auth_handler.add_password('realm', 'host', proxy_id, proxy_pw)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, proxy_auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

request = urllib2.Request("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n',   '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. I forgot to mention that the my proxy block works well for other http web scaping. My urllib2 request block works well when there's no proxy. But they don't work together when there's both proxy and http authentication....Therefore just changing the code for proxy set up didn't help much. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question. The code was totally correct. I used the wrong proxy http so that's causing all the problem.